# codeigniter upload file $_FILES returns empty array array(0) { }

Tags: php, forms, file, codeigniter, upload

I have a function to upload an image which inserts the image name into the database perfectly fine. i created a new function called `edit()` with the exact same code which allows the user to edit a form and upload an image. this image name will update the existing image name in the database.

However, every time the user edits the form and chooses a new image, instead of saving the new image name, it wipes the the previous name from the database and display nothing.

my controller:

```
  public function edit(){     

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[news.title]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('notes', 'notes', 'required|xss_clean|trim');


      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
                $data['error'] =  '';
            $data['page_title']="Edit News";
                $this->load->view("edit_news_form",$data);

           }
          else {

               $new = array(
               'upload_path' => "./images/news",
               'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPG",
               'overwrite' =>False,          
               'max_height' => "768",
               'max_width' => "1024"           
               );

                  $this->load->library('upload', $new);
                  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

           if(isset($_FILES)) {       

                  if($this->upload->do_upload())
                     {

                   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload>data());
                         $this->load->view('manage_news',$data);
                      }
                      else {
              if(empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){ $imagename ='';}

                   else {    

                         $message2 = "Please choose another file type. gif,jpg,png,jpeg ";
                         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');</script>";

                         redirect('resetPasswordController/edit_news_form', 'refresh');

                       }                                  
              }
              }

            $this->db->trans_start();         


        $imagename = $this->upload->data();

        $data = array(
            'image'=>$imagename['file_name'],      
            );
        $this->users_model->update($id,$data);
        $this->db->trans_complete();

          $message2 = "The selected news has been edited";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');</script>";


          redirect('resetPasswordController/manage_news', 'refresh');

    }

   }
```

my view:

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('resetPasswordController/news');?>
 <label>Image</label>
 <input name = "userfile" type="file" />
 <label> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Continue">
 </label>
```

my model:

```
    function update($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news',$data);
    }
```

my model function is working because it is updating the database to nothing.i think the problem is with the view and controller.

when i type `var_dump($_FILES)` it returns an empty array which means no file was selected.

how can i fix this?

Comment: have you close your form tag????

Comment: yes i have. the form is working because i used the exact form code for another upload situation. its a logic problem with my controller. its not reading the file the user selects in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $this->load->library('upload');
                    $config = array(
                                'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
                                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx',
                                'max_size'      => 10000,
                                'overwrite'     => FALSE
                        );

                    $files = $_FILES;
                    $cpt = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

                   for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
                   { 

                        $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $files['file']['name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $files['file']['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $files['file']['error'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $files['file']['size'][$i];    

                        $this->upload->initialize($config);
                        $this->upload->do_upload();

                        <!-- INSERT DB HERE --->
                   }
```

you can use this as your reference it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you loaded the CodeIgniter form helper. $this->load->helper('form') before your form controller. Or you can load it automatically using application/config/autoload.php by Putting this $autoload['helper'] = array('form'); Hope it will work.

Comment: your form link  <?php echo form_open_multipart('resetPasswordController/news');?> which is submitted to news function in the resetPasswordController controller. But you working on public function edit(). Is the data submitted to right destination that you want?

Comment: sorry, forgot to change that when i copied to text. it is going to the correct function.

Comment: <?php echo form_open_multipart('resetPasswordController/edit');?>